# How can I add column titles into a Dataset?

Tags: dataset

What I am trying to do is to add columns titles into my data set that has unit information.
First I create a list of countries:

```
Countries = {"UnitedStates", "Mexico", "Canada", "Brazil","Argentina", "Peru", "Ecuador", "CostaRica", "ElSalvador"}
```

Then I compute for each country the population using `CountryData`.

```
populations = CountryData[#, "Population"] & /@ Countries
```

Now I proceed to create and association and then then data  set.

```
dat = Dataset[AssociationThread[Countries -> populations]]
```

[image]

But when I try to add names to columns using `dat[All, <|"1" -> "Country", "2" -> "Population"|>]` I get this error.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you need is more like this:

```
dat=Dataset[MapThread[<|"Country" -> #1,"Population" -> #2|> &, {Countries, populations}]]
```

[image]

The structure you are looking for is one association per row, with the keys equal to the column headings.

Comment: Yeah it worked nice.

Comment: A more natural way to do this is to use `AssociationThread[]`: `Dataset[AssociationThread[{"Country", "Population"}, #] & /@ Transpose[{Countries, populations}]]`

Answer (score 4):

One option could be

```
 PrependTo[dat, <|"Country" -> "Population"|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know how the semantics of your data set will change now by adding the title right into the data itself like this.  I think normally column titles are added at the end, for display purposes and not part of the actual dataset itself.

Comment: Yes that correct, I am using this as an example.